# is there a way to easy open a batch file with using number & letter keys?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I started yet with programming in cmd and vbs.
I'm now trying to make a simple tiny program which shows an ascii-art animation if you press a key, but I don't know how I have to program input with no pressing enter after you press a key. can someone help me?

p.s. I'm not an expert in programming, so please keep it easy.

Comment: Take a look at the [`choice` command](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)...

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at AHK:

https://autohotkey.com/

There are examples and tutorials, it is the easiest solution for the level of expertise you mentioned you have.

Another method that does not use third-party software is creating a shortcut for your bat file. Then, right-click on the shorcut. There, on the Shorcut tab you have the option to set Shortcut key:

[image: Printscreen]